# Mootools equivalent of jQuery's before

Tags: jquery, mootools

does mootools have equivalent of jQuery's `before`?
Or if not, how can I do similar functionality in mootools?

For example, I got result from ajax and I want to insert HTML-code of result before some element.

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>

  </div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

I want to insert some HTML code (which is string) before `.loader`.
I can't use JSON, or HTML like object in this issue.

I have function which inserts HTML into div:

```
function appendHTML(elem, html){
    if ($type(html) != 'string') return false;
    var temp = new Element('div');
    temp.set('html', html);
    elem.adopt(temp.childNodes);
    return this;
}
```

But I want insert HTML code before div, not into.
Thanks!

Comment: I mean HTML code string, not object!

Comment: It's *easier* to work with Element Objects instead of passing strings around. If you are passing html from your server-side via ajax, you could save some time by passing only the data you requre (and use [Request.JSON](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.JSON)), and render the element as per my answer below.

Comment: I get from server only HTML. I don't want to get in JSON coz I want to insert blocks of every type.

Answer (score 6):

When you [inject](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject) your element into the DOM, you can pass in a second argument that says where the element should go. The default is `bottom`.

```
new Element('div', {
    "class": 'className',
    html: 'Some html'
}).inject(existingEl, 'before');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`inject()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject) method:

```
myElement.inject(el[, where]);
```

Here is an example of inserting `myFirstElement` before `mySecondElement`:

```
myFirstElement.inject(mySecondElement, 'before');
```